# What are the differences between Rundeck and Quartz (Job Scheduler)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling, rundeck

I am doing some research on job schedulers compatible with node.js and Rundeck and Quartz came across. I tried to understand the difference but didn't quite get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rundeck uses Quartz as the underlying scheduling library.

Comment: Hi Alex. Can you provide a bit more information or a link where we can read about it? Can you help us with an example where Quartz job is scheduled as a Rundeck job?